# I want to create a Candy Machine That has unlimited items or let's say 10k

Tags: metaplex, sugar

I'm creating a candy machine using metaplex sugar how do I configure it to have 10k items if possible unlimited items without having to create multiple JSON files and images? I tried hidden settings but when I mint it print does not have any items here is my candy machine code.

```
{
  "tokenStandard": "nft",
  "number": 0,
  "symbol": "BDP",
  "sellerFeeBasisPoints": 500,
  "isMutable": true,
  "isSequential": true,
  "creators": [
    {
      "address": "",
      "share": 100
    }
  ],
  "uploadMethod": "nft_storage",
  "ruleSet": null,
  "awsConfig": null,
  "sdriveApiKey": null,
  "nftStorageAuthToken": "",
  "shdwStorageAccount": null,
  "pinataConfig": null,
  "hiddenSettings": {
    "name": "",
    "uri": "",
    "hash": ""
  },
  "guards": {
    "default": {
      "botTax": null,
      "solPayment": {
        "value": 0.01,
        "destination": ""
      },
      "tokenPayment": null,
      "startDate": null,
      "thirdPartySigner": null,
      "tokenGate": null,
      "gatekeeper": null,
      "endDate": null,
      "allowList": null,
      "mintLimit": null,
      "nftPayment": null,
      "redeemedAmount": null,
      "addressGate": null,
      "nftGate": null,
      "nftBurn": null,
      "tokenBurn": null,
      "freezeSolPayment": null,
      "freezeTokenPayment": null,
      "programGate": null,
      "allocation": null,
      "token2022Payment": null
    },
    "groups": null
  },
  "maxEditionSupply": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference. This can be done using hiddenConfigs

after creating the candy machine you have to update the number of items using the js binding library. For those who don't have any idea read the README.md of this repo

[dinu-jam](https://%20https://github.com/oasisMystre/daddy-inu-solana-jam.git)

Comment: When writing answers, it's best to not include links, as those could be dead in the future